# Can I determine which datasource a CFQuery has used without debug information?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfquery

I do not have access to turn on debugging information for myself on a server that I'm working on.  I'd like to remove the datasource attribute from cfQuery tags to have them use the default datasource for the application.  However, I want to be able to verify afterwards that they are actually using the correct datasource (and not errantly pulling something from some code that I'm not familiar with).

The result variable, according to the livedocs, does not contain the datasource used.  Is there any way to determine this after a query is run?

Comment: You could query the default datasource not using ColdFusion and either check that the data ColdFusion was supposed to write is actually there, or compare results of select queries.

Comment: @DanBracuk Thanks; that's a good suggestion.  I've already been spot checking a few doing this, but it's a bit laborious.  I was hoping for a more streamlined solution.

Comment: If the `datasource` attribute is not set on a `cfquery` newer version of ColdFusion will use the 'default' one set up in Application.cfc - or it will throw an error. There really is no other way to 'inject' a datasource name - unbless you are using a custom tag to execute your queries.

Comment: @scottStroz Thanks.  There are custom tags and cfcs, and many subfolders have their own Application.cfcs.  Many files also include files from other subfolders.  We've already run across one issue where the live datasource was being used, even with no specified datasource and the root Application.cfc specifying the dev datasource.

Comment: @ScottStroz - can't you dump out the #application# scope? I thought it contained the Datasource name? no?

Comment: it is only stored in Application scope if you stored it there. The default datasource is stored in the `this` scope of Application.cfc. You could do `writeDump( this )` in Application.cfc.

Comment: @ScottStroz But what if another Application.cfc overwrites the default datasource before the writeDump(this) in the parent Application.cfc runs?

Comment: Another strategy would be to prevent the LIVE datasources from working from the DEV CF servers... If you have access to the LIVE database as an admin, maybe you can limit calls to it to only come from the LIVE CF server? Or if you have access to the CF Admin, you can go into the datasource settings and check the "Disable Connections" (CF 10+, I think), or at least go and uncheck all the "Allowed SQL" options. You'll quickly find out, via errors, if you're using the correct datasource everywhere.

Comment: If there is an Application.cfc in a sub-folder, ColdFusion will stop looking for any others when a file in that folder is called, so the 'parent' Application.cfc will not get executed at all. I have never had a need to use Application.cfc in a sub-folder unless I was creating a separate ColdFusion application, in which case, I would have no need for the 'parent' file.